# Paragraphs not appearing in order using fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, append, paragraph

I want the names to fade in in order. It currently looks terrible animation-wise. I want first name appear then fall down, the second taking its place, then second falls down etc

```js
var friends = ["John", "Max", "Jeena", "Suki"];
for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
  $("body").append("<p>" + friends[i] + "</p>");
  $("p").hide().fadeIn(1000 * (i + 2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're calling `hide()` and `fadeIn` again on all existing elements in every iteration.

To make this work as you expect you need to only apply those method calls to the *current* `p` element which you create in the loop logic.

In the following example note the use of CSS to hide the `p` by default instead of jQuery's `hide()` method. This is to avoid any possible FOUC.

```js
["John", "Max", "Jeena", "Suki"].forEach((name, i) => {
  $(`<p>${name}</p>`).appendTo('body').fadeIn(1000 * (i + 2));
});
```

```css
p { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Update*

> Can I make it so until the 1st name's animation is finished other's dont start to appear?

Sure, you can use `delay()` to make each animation wait a predetermined amount of time to let the previous ones complete:

```js
["John", "Max", "Jeena", "Suki"].forEach((name, i) => {
  $(`<p>${name}</p>`).appendTo('body').delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
p { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can I make it so until the 1st name's animation is finished other's dont start to appear?

Comment: Yes, use `delay()`. I updated the answer to show you how to do that